# dnsmasq not allocating IPs in full range configured

Tags: dnsmasq

I have dnsmasq configured to allocate IPs in the range 10.10.10.2 to 10.10.10.62. However it only seems to be allocating IPs in the range 10.10.10.45 to 10.10.10.62. When this smaller range is full no more IPs are allocated.

My dnsmasq.conf is

```
server=10.10.10.2@ens192

except-interface=lo,virbr0

dhcp-range=10.10.10.2,10.10.10.62,24h

dhcp-boot=gpxe.kpxe

# Include all files in /etc/dnsmasq.d except RPM backup files
conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d,.rpmnew,.rpmsave,.rpmorig

# NTP Server
dhcp-option=42,194.35.252.7,194.207.34.9,130.88.203.12
#
# # DNS
dhcp-option=6,10.10.0.11,10.10.0.12
```

The dnsmasq logs show `DHCPDISCOVER no address available`

dnsmasq is running in docker running debian:buster-slim. This issue was seen with alpine too though.

Comment: What is X.X.X? Are you assigning global IP addresses? You should [avoid posting fake information](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963) when possible.

Comment: Hi. I have updated it with more representative IP addresses. Sorry about that

Comment: You seem to have the host's own IP address within the DHCP server range. That might be a problem.